# Typescript: how to declare a function type for a rest function param?

Tags: typescript

This function accepts 2 parameters: param a is a string and b is a function that returns a string. I'm trying to call it with a rest parameter and type it accordingly.

But at line 10 (last line) the TS compiler is throwing "Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TFoo'.ts(2345)".

```js
type TFoo = () => string | string;

function foo (...args: TFoo[]) {
  let [a, b] = args;

  if (typeof b === 'function') {
    b  = b();
  }  
}

foo('a', () => 'baz');
```

I expect TS to allow string or functions to these function parameters.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: the type `() => string | string` would mean `() => (string | string)` i.e. just the function `() => string` rather than `(() => string) | string`, however, if you put brackets around the function type it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the order of precendence in how types are declared, as the comment from Ahmed suggests in his comment.

One solution is this:

```
type FooFunc = () => string
type FooInput = string | FooFunc

function foo (...args: FooInput[]) {
```

Another is:

```
type FooInput = string | (() => string)

function foo (...args: FooInput[]) {
```

I'd have the function as:

```
function foo (a: FooInput, b: FooInput) {
```

but maybe you have a reason for expecting an unknown number of args.